# How to compare the rows of two tables and delete only if no matching row

Tags: c#

I want to be able to delete a row in gridview1 if there are no rows in gridview2 which has exactly the same values as gridview1

What should I put in onRowDeleting?

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {


      int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;

      GridViewRow theRow = GridView1.Rows[selectedRow];
      string str = ("Delete TDLoanRate where Id=@id");
      SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(str, con);

      insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(theRow.Cells[0].Text));

      using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
      {
           insert.Connection = con;
           con.Open();
           sda.SelectCommand = insert;
           sda.Fill(dt);
           GridView1.DataSource = dt;
           GridView1.DataBind();
      }
```

Comment: Use `MERGE` sql query and based on the query result update your DataGridView. [Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data by Using MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just compare rows? Normally I would ask things like `what have you tried?` but its monday, bad enough.

Check this out:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
DataGridView dgv2 = new DataGridView();

// Iterate on the rowcount
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
    // Compare each row and count occurences.
    int occurs = dgv2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => row == dgv.Rows[i]).Count();
    // If no row is equal
    if (occurs <= 0)
        // Delete it.
        dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: I am very sorry for not saying that actually the gridviews are not on the same page hence i need to retrieve straight from the database

Comment: But it isnt changing a thing isnt it? After selecting from database you are filling a `DataGridView`s so you can use my method or is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I might be misintepreted. what i mean is that there is only one gridview in the page hence i need to compare it with a table that is in the database

Comment: And you want to delete from database if the row is missing on the `DataGridView`?